# Multiple Conditional If Statements in Excel to Return Single Value

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, nested-if

My worksheet has 2 pertinent columns:

Column C (which assigns an Asset Topic to each of 3,600 assets) 
Column D (which assigns an Asset Type to each of 3,600 assets)

Asset Topic is independent of Asset Type.

Mock-up of Asset Topic and Asset Type data:
[image: image description]

On a new worksheet, I want to show a chart that confirms whether each of certain Asset Topics has at least one asset of each of certain asset types.

mock up of chart
[image: image description]

For example, if Asset Topic is "Bananas," I want to return a value of "true" if there is at least one presentation, order guide, FAQ, demo, data sheet, price sheet for "Bananas." If all these asset types are not present, I want a value of "false."

I've tried variations of `IF/AND/OR, VLOOKUP/INDEX/MATCH and INDEX/MATCH/ISNUMBER/SEARCH`, but I keep getting `#VALUE!`, `#N/A!` errors or incorrect "false" results. For example, I entered the following as an array formula:

```
{
   =IF
      (AND
         ('sheet_name'!$C:$C="Bananas", 'sheet_name'!$D:$D="presentations"), "true", "false")
}
```

It returned a result of false; however, there are at least 3 entries in Column C for "bananas" with corresponding entries in Column D for "presentations" (based on my actual data, not the mockup above).

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You should be able to use COUNTIFS() but without more information it is hard to give you a concrete answer.  Please mock up some data and expected output, so we can better understand your needs.

Comment: Maybe even include one or more of the formulas that didn't quite work. Listing a bunch of functions that *'keep getting #VALUE!, #N/A! errors'* does nothing to help your cause.